# Build SQL Query to retrive Name from ParentTable having Child Data with both address Types (primary & secondary)

Tags: sql, parent-child

parentTable

```
=======================================
parentid(PK), name, timestamp
1, Dr John, 2022-01-12 00:00:00
2, Dr Smita, 2022-02-13 00:00:00
3, Dr Roy, 2022-08-13 00:00:00
4, Dr Shawn, 2022-08-14 00:00:00
```

childTable

```
=======================================
childId(PK), parentId(FK to parentTable.parentid), addressType, location, timestamp
1, 1, primary, Pune, 2022-01-12 00:00:00
2, 1, secondary, Mumbai, 2022-01-12 00:00:00
3, 2, primary, Delhi, 2022-01-13 00:00:00
4, 3, primary, Dubai, 2022-08-13 00:00:00
5, 3, secondary, London, 2022-08-13 00:00:00
6, 4, primary, Banglore, 2022-08-14 00:00:00
```

Result of Query Should be:
Name
Dr John
Dr Roy

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do. Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: it seems to be a homework

Answer (score 0):

```
select   name
from     parentTable join childTable using(parentid, timestamp)
group by parentid, name
having   max(addressType) <> min(addressType)
```

| name |
| --- |
| Dr John |
| Dr Roy |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dIuZ5PAL)